# Calling a scanner the number of times the user inputted in java

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

This is one of my very first java projects and I'm trying to make a mini calculator and right now I'm working on addition.

What I want it to do is like it will ask the user how many numbers they want to add and then after you type all the numbers, and the java code has to get all the numbers that inputted.

Here's the addition part that doesn't work so far:

```
    private static void Addition() { //I already added the Scanner plugin
        System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");

        Scanner adds = new Scanner(System.in);
        int addsput = adds.nextInt();

        Scanner numa = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int addloop=1; addloop>addsput; addloop++) {

            int numaput = adds.nextInt();
            //somehow I want to get all the numbers

        }

    //Here I want to add all the numbers they typed
    }
```

So I hope you get the idea. Any help would be great, because I've been searching for about an hour to get this figured out. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean it "doesnt work"? what does it do? what do you expect it to do? it is not enough to say "i hope you get the idea". provide more detail please

Comment: Why do you have 2 scanners?

Comment: Ok I'll explain what it's suppose to do :P lol

Comment: The first scanner is to see how many numbers they want, and the second one is to scan the numbers the user has typed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either read the values into an array, or find the sum as you read the values.

You only need one `Scanner` object, and your `for` loop had some issues:

```
private static void addition() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");
    int amountNumbers = input.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < amountNumbers; counter++) {
        sum += input.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

Using an array:

```
private static void addition() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");
    int[] numbers = new int[input.nextInt()];

    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        numbers[index] = input.nextInt();
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        sum += numbers[index];
    }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

---

Here is a more advanced way to do it using [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) from Java 8:

```
private static void addition() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");
    int amountNumbers = input.nextInt();

    int sum = IntStream.generate(input::nextInt)
                       .limit(amountNumbers)
                       .sum();

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. I will probably learn about arrays soon, because I never really needed them until now.

Comment: @MattGotJava I made an edit to show how to do it using an array, and also a more advanced way to do it (the way I would do it).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I would recommend changing:
You only need 1 scanner. And as for adding to a sum, if you make the variable before the loop, you can just add to the sum in the same line you take input.

You also had the < sign mixed up with a > sign. You want the loop to go until the variable addloop has been incremented the amount of times the user wants to input a number to add. Therefore, the loop should continue until it reaches the number the user entered, rather than the other way around.

```
   System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");

    Scanner adds = new Scanner(System.in);
    int addsput = adds.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < addsput; i++){
        sum += adds.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
```